# Soft-hyphen hides subsequent text when using Opera 12.16

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown, editor, opera

I saw [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/10854/2308) over at german.stackexchange.com and thought 'Hey, a typing error! Let's fix it.'
[image]

I went into edit mode and saw that the word is already written correctly: 'streichen'.
[image]

I am confused. Why doesn't SE show the last 4 characters? I opened the same question in multiple different browsers, all with their newest builds. And only my (old) Opera 12.16 doesn't render it properly.

It took me some minutes to figure out that a [soft hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) (ASCII 173; `&shy;`) sits between *strei* and *chen*.
[image]

Can this somehow be fixed by Stack Exchange?

Comment: Based on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) Opera 12 should be supported...

Comment: @rene The answer is a bit outdated but you're still correct, while Windows and OS X are on v20 right now (release schedule similar to Chrome), Linux is still on v12.16

Comment: A month ago edited and now already outdated! Time flies if you're having fun.

Comment: How is balpha's answer relevant, though? You're seeing that in an answer, not in a comment (which is the only place those auto-insertions occur). That soft hyphen was inserted by the *author of that post*, or possibly the source he copied it from. Aside from that, this is Opera's problem, not ours. Hiding text after a soft hyphen sounds like a pretty *serious* bug and past removing all soft hyphens (which isn't going to happen) there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: @animuson I see. I removed the second part regarding balphas answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed.  (Opera 12.16 on Linux here too.)

This only seems to happen inside code blocks (specifically, elements styled with `white-space: pre`; inline code with `white-space: pre-wrap` seems to be fine).

I don't see any real reason to have soft hyphens inside code blocks (except maybe in the mobile view, but the styling is different there anyway), so SE could just strip them out.  In fact, adding a client-side fix to [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) shouldn't be difficult, either.

That said, this really is a bug in Opera, and should be [reported](https://bugs.opera.com/wizarddesktop/).*

Test case:

```
The long­er words in this text will be trun­cat­ed in Op­era.
```

`These words will not be trun­cat­ed in Op­era.`

<sub>*) In fact, I've just done that; the bug ID is DSK-388102.</sub>

---

**Ps.** While waiting for an official fix, I've added a client-side fix for this issue to the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.10 (which should also have significantly improved Opera compatibility in general).  Basically, what my fix does is simply remove any soft hyphens found inside `<pre>` tags on Opera.

I've also tried to make sure that the removal code gets re-run if any new posts are loaded by AJAX, or when the editor preview is updated.  Alas, this latter feature seems to work somewhat unreliably, with the editor hooks sometimes failing to be applied.  If anyone can figure out why that might be happening, please let me know!  In the mean time, reloading the page seems to usually fix it.